# Plotting pandas timedelta

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has two datetime64 columns and one timedelta64 column that is the difference between the two columns. I'm trying to plot a histogram of the timedelta column to visualize the time differences between the two events.

However, just using `df['time_delta']` results in:
`TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('<m8[ns]') and dtype('float64')`

Trying to convert the timedelta column to : `float--> df2 = df1['time_delta'].astype(float)` 
results in:
`TypeError: cannot astype a timedelta from [timedelta64[ns]] to [float64]`

How would one create a histogram of pandas timedelta data?

Comment: How did you finally plot it? I'm unable to simply plot a series with value datatype timedelta64. The error says 'no numeric data to plot'!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Here are ways to convert timedeltas, docs are [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/timeseries.html#time-deltas)

```
In [2]: pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(5),unit='d')+pd.to_timedelta(1,unit='s')
Out[2]: 
0   0 days, 00:00:01
1   1 days, 00:00:01
2   2 days, 00:00:01
3   3 days, 00:00:01
4   4 days, 00:00:01
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Convert to seconds (is an exact conversion)

```
In [3]: (pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(5),unit='d')+pd.to_timedelta(1,unit='s')).astype('timedelta64[s]')
Out[3]: 
0         1
1     86401
2    172801
3    259201
4    345601
dtype: float64
```

Convert using astype will round to that unit

```
In [4]: (pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(5),unit='d')+pd.to_timedelta(1,unit='s')).astype('timedelta64[D]')
Out[4]: 
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
dtype: float64
```

Division will give an exact repr

```
In [5]: (pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(5),unit='d')+pd.to_timedelta(1,unit='s')) / np.timedelta64(1,'D')
Out[5]: 
0    0.000012
1    1.000012
2    2.000012
3    3.000012
4    4.000012
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! I totally skipped over the to_timedelta section when looking for a from_timedelta...

Comment: umm... so these are some ways to convert timedeltas... but the question was asking for ways to plot timedelta information. Care to elaborate??

Comment: you can convert timedelts to float or string to plot; these are not supported currently ; though could be via a pull request from the community

Comment: To plot timedeltas, convert the new (float) pd.series to pd.dataframe, and then use the native  DF plotting - i.e. `pd.DataFrame(pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(5),unit='d') / np.timedelta64(1,'D')).boxplot()`

Answer (score 41):

You can plot nice histograms using the numpy timedelta data types.

For example:

```
df['time_delta'].astype('timedelta64[s]').plot.hist()
```

will produce a histogram of the time deltas in seconds. To use minutes instead, you could do this:

```
(df['time_delta'].astype('timedelta64[s]') / 60).plot.hist()
```

or use `[m]` timedelta.

```
df['time_delta'].astype('timedelta64[m]').plot.hist()
```

Here's list of other time delta types (from [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units)) you might want, depending on the resolution you need:

```
Code    Meaning Time span (relative)    Time span (absolute)
h   hour    +/- 1.0e15 years    [1.0e15 BC, 1.0e15 AD]
m   minute  +/- 1.7e13 years    [1.7e13 BC, 1.7e13 AD]
s   second  +/- 2.9e11 years    [2.9e11 BC, 2.9e11 AD]
ms  millisecond +/- 2.9e8 years [ 2.9e8 BC, 2.9e8 AD]
us  microsecond +/- 2.9e5 years [290301 BC, 294241 AD]
ns  nanosecond  +/- 292 years   [ 1678 AD, 2262 AD]
ps  picosecond  +/- 106 days    [ 1969 AD, 1970 AD]
fs  femtosecond +/- 2.6 hours   [ 1969 AD, 1970 AD]
as  attosecond  +/- 9.2 seconds [ 1969 AD, 1970 AD]
```

Comment: what is `s` and `m` in `timedelta64[s]` or `timedelta64[m]`?

Comment: They indicate that the accuracy of the timedelta `s` means seconds, and `m` is minutes in this case. Keep in mind that these will be cut of rather than rounded, when you convert to a higher unit.

Comment: I think @mattb was referring to the fact that the code doesn't compile. I believe it's supposed to be `df['time_delta'].astype("timedelta64[m]")`.

Comment: .astype('timedelta64[m]') seems dropping the decimal after minute. i.e. 2.4 min becomes 2 min

Answer (score 17):

How about

```
df['time_delta'].dt.days.hist()
```

...? (Where you can use `seconds`, `microseconds`, or `nanoseconds` instead of `days` depending on your needs / your data).

Comment: And add e.g. `.apply(lambda x: x/3600)` before `.hist()` if you need to work with other units.

Answer (score 5):

Another method (that worked for me) is to simply divide by a `Timedelta` :

```
plt.hist(df['time_delta']/pd.Timedelta(minutes=1), bins=20)
```