# Can't plot from csv file with pandas: ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, pandas, plot

So i read a *.csv file with Pandas, but if I want to plot it, it shows me the following error,

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '23:00:00'`

I read and print the following *.csv file with,

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(Location_l, sep=";") 
df1
```

[Here the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz5NA.png)

I tried to change 'time' to timedelta but it still woulnd't plot it.

How do I convert 'time' in order to plot df1?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `df1 = pd.read_csv(Location_l, sep=";", parse_dates=['time'])` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want plot `timedelta`, now it is [not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543909/plotting-pandas-timedelta), so possible solution is convert `time` column to [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""time;Watt
00:00:00;0
01:00:00;0
02:00:00;0
03:00:00;0
04:00:00;0
05:00:00;45
06:00:00;56
07:00:00;88"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
converter = {'time':lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(x)}
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";", converters=converter)

df['time_in_sec'] = df['time'].dt.total_seconds()
print (df)
       time  Watt  time_in_sec
0  00:00:00     0          0.0
1  01:00:00     0       3600.0
2  02:00:00     0       7200.0
3  03:00:00     0      10800.0
4  04:00:00     0      14400.0
5  05:00:00    45      18000.0
6  06:00:00    56      21600.0
7  07:00:00    88      25200.0

df.plot(x='time_in_sec', y='Watt')
```

Another solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""time;Watt
00:00:00;0
01:00:00;0
02:00:00;0
03:00:00;0
04:00:00;0
05:00:00;45
06:00:00;56
07:00:00;88"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";")
df['time_in_sec'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time']).dt.total_seconds()
print (df)
       time  Watt  time_in_sec
0  00:00:00     0          0.0
1  01:00:00     0       3600.0
2  02:00:00     0       7200.0
3  03:00:00     0      10800.0
4  04:00:00     0      14400.0
5  05:00:00    45      18000.0
6  06:00:00    56      21600.0
7  07:00:00    88      25200.0

df.plot(x='time_in_sec', y='Watt')
```

Solution with parsing `timedelta` as `datetime` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and then convert to [`time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""time;Watt
00:00:00;0
01:00:00;0
02:00:00;0
03:00:00;0
04:00:00;0
05:00:00;45
06:00:00;56
07:00:00;88"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";", parse_dates=['time'])

df['time'] = df['time'].dt.time
print (df)
       time  Watt
0  00:00:00     0
1  01:00:00     0
2  02:00:00     0
3  03:00:00     0
4  04:00:00     0
5  05:00:00    45
6  06:00:00    56
7  07:00:00    88

df.plot(x='time', y='Watt')
```

### ---

Another possible solution is set index in `read_csv`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""time;Watt
00:00:00;0
01:00:00;0
02:00:00;0
03:00:00;0
04:00:00;0
05:00:00;45
06:00:00;56
07:00:00;88"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";", index_col=['time'])
df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df.index).total_seconds()
print (df)
         Watt
time         
0.0         0
3600.0      0
7200.0      0
10800.0     0
14400.0     0
18000.0    45
21600.0    56
25200.0    88

df['Watt'].plot()
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""time;Watt
00:00:00;0
01:00:00;0
02:00:00;0
03:00:00;0
04:00:00;0
05:00:00;45
06:00:00;56
07:00:00;88"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";", parse_dates=True, index_col=['time'])
df.index = df.index.time
print (df)
          Watt
00:00:00     0
01:00:00     0
02:00:00     0
03:00:00     0
04:00:00     0
05:00:00    45
06:00:00    56
07:00:00    88

df['Watt'].plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

might be because you have null or N/A data in your dataframe 
You want to use " df2.fillna(0) "