# Getting difference in two datetime columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe and it shows the types as

```
signup_time       151112 non-null datetime64[ns]
purchase_time     151112 non-null datetime64[ns]
```

The actual values are in the format `2015-02-24 22:55:49`

When I subtract two rows I get the difference in days like `52 days 03:51:22`
how can I get the difference values in seconds

Answer (score 11):

**1)** Use `.dt.total_seconds()`

```
(df.purchase_time - df.signup_time).dt.total_seconds()
```

**2)** Or use `np.timedelta64(1, 's')`

```
(df.purchase_time - df.signup_time) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
```

**3)** Or use `.astype('timedelta64[s]')`

```
(df.purchase_time - df.signup_time).astype('timedelta64[s]')
```