# How to get the time from column, which contains numbers in pandas?

Tags: pandas, time, integer

I want to convert the AVG column's numbers to hour(s):minute(s) form.

- if it is more than 24h, I still want only hour:minutes form like this 73:45
- consider these numbers as seconds

plus
I want to show the AVG time of these activities on a bar.
All the activities.
I us this for it:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Activity']).mean()
```

I want to see the hour:minutes

```
df = pd.read_csv('practice.csv')

df['AVG'] = df['AVG'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

out:

*Activity                           AVG
0    sleep 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000221
1    sleep 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000201
2     swim 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000300
3      run 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001768
4       tv 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000105*

Comment: How looks input data in `AVG` column?

Comment: Activity AVG
sleep 86400
sleep 20201
swim 86700
run 11768
tv 85105
dance 50406
sleep 50389

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First aggregate `mean`, convert column to timedeltas and format it in custom function:

```
df2 = df.groupby('Activity', as_index=False)['AVG'].mean()

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/51102096/2901002
def f(x):
    ts = x.total_seconds()
    hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return ('{}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes)) 


df2['AVG'] = pd.to_timedelta(df2['AVG'], unit='s').apply(f)
```

Comment: raise TypeError("no numeric data to plot")
TypeError: no numeric data to plot

but I think I am getting it..
so, I will try something

Comment: @ptr808 - If need plotting use seconds, but if need hours or minutes use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45892320/how-to-plot-timedelta-data-from-a-pandas-dataframe) solution without `.apply(f)`

Comment: I cannot solve it.
I do not understand.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v36C7g8OWeI0MHzuVknM5hWoW4Bhr4Yk/view?usp=drivesdk