# Format pandas y axis to show time instead of total seconds

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, label, duration

i have measurements in a dataframe. Columns are different objects. Index is a datetime64 index. Now for each date I have a measurement in total seconds (int) for each column.

Everything plots quite nice, my only problem instead of showing 6000 seconds on the y axis i want to show 1:40 to indicate 1 hour and 40 minutes.

How can I actually achieve this?

```
day         Object1  Object2
2017-01-01     6000     1234
```

I want

```
day         Object1  Object2
2017-01-01  1:40:00  00:20:34
```

Can you hint me on how to do it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible, but [`ploting timedelta`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543909/plotting-pandas-timedelta) is not supported yet natively.

```
df['Object1'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Object1'], unit='s')
df['Object2'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Object2'], unit='s')
```

Or:

```
cols = ['Object1', 'Object2']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(x, unit='s'))
```

---

```
print (df)
          day  Object1  Object2
0  2017-01-01 01:40:00 00:20:34
```

But is possible it by `FuncFormatter`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Object1': [6000, 4000, 3000], 'Object2':[3000,5000,2110]})

import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
import datetime

def func(x, pos):
    return str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=x))
fmt = tkr.FuncFormatter(func)


ax = df.plot(x='Object1', y='Object2', rot=90)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Mention  *ploting timedelta is not supported yet* , definitely deserve many upvotes : -)

Comment: It definitely helps. Now is it also possible to tell it to use 30 minutes intervals as tick intervals for y axis?

Comment: found it ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(1*60*30))